# Yelp Fusion API - Pulling Specific Business Data Using PHP And JSON

Tags: php, json, api, yelp

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Yelp Fusion API with PHP to return the Yelp `rating` and `location` for a specific business.

I've looked for a code sample for the Yelp Fusion Business API in action, but I can't find one. I did find an example for the Yelp Fusion Search API (https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/blob/master/fusion/php/sample.php), but I'm not a developer and I'm struggling modifying it to work for my needs.

Can someone please show me how to develop a php file that will get the [business data](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business) for a specific business (pick anyone or use `the-crack-shack-encinitas`) and how to echo these individual pieces of data (`ratings` and `location`)?

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Todd

High School Web Design Teacher and Life Long Learner

**Documentation**

https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get help on the Yelp GitHub Page
https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/issues/202

Below is the solution I cam up with and it works.

```
$arr = json_decode($pretty_response);
echo "Rating is - " . $arr->rating . "<br>" . "Address<br>" . $arr->location->display_address[0] . "<br>" . $arr->location->display_address[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but i suspect based on my understanding you might not be using authentication for calling APIs. There might be issues with client_id, token and client secret. Please go through this documentation

https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/get_started

and scroll to section Get an access token

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much out there yet but this is what I've used to convert my API v2 code from https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/blob/master/fusion/php/sample.php